# Since "india" is Bharat, what is the scriptural term for Indian?

Tags: india

From what I understand, India is a term that Britain put on Bharat (And in "india", the natives call it Bharat)..

So the name of your land (in your native tongue/language), is Bharat, but what is the term in scripture, for what in English is "an indian" or "indians" ?

Comment: This question belongs on [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [hinduism.se]. Language questions are off-topic for our site. As suggested by ruben2020, try [linguistics.se].

Comment: There was a King named BHARATA. BHÂRATA (notice the diacritical mark above the A) means the descendants of BHARATA.

Comment: hindi for "indian" is  "bhartiya" . it is pronounced as "bhaarteey"

Comment: @ruben2020 i've hopefully adjusted the question to make it on topic

Comment: @Sarvabhouma i've hopefully adjusted the question to make it on topic

Comment: "what is the term in scripture, for what in English is "an indian" or "indians"" Do scripture suggest what is Hindi, English or any other language? I think you mean a dictionary. Also make sure what you mean by "your". There are many. This is not limited to a single country. Name of many user's land is not Bharat. I think this is a duplicate now. But please avoid asking language questions here. They are off-topic and don't expect scriptures to talk about English, regional languages. Linguists speak better about this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scriptures, the term used for Indian is **भारती (Bhāratī)** as mentioned in [Vishnu Purana: Book II: Chapter III](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp060.htm):

> uttaraṃ yatsamudrasya himādreścaiva dakṣiṇam
>
> varṣaṃ tadbhārataṃ nāma **bhāratī** yatra santatiḥ
>
> The country that lies north of the ocean, and south of the snowy mountains, is called Bhárata, for there dwell **Bhāratī** (the descendants of Bharata).

In Hindi, term for Indian is **भारतीय** (**Bhāratīy**).

Comment: Language questions are off-topic for the site. Please don't answer off-topic quesstions as they prevent automatic deletion of off-topic questions.

Comment: if q can be answered from scriptures it's on topic thats what i can conclude from other Qs on the site..else how history, geography, ayurveda, sanskrit Qs are on topic..? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Read [meta-tag:faq], [help] pages to know what's off-topic or on-topic. Answers don't decide what is on-topic or off-topic. Question does. Whoever gave the definition you said didn't know SE way of scope. There was a question about presence of onions in pickles. If some scripture answers that question, should we reopen it and answer? History of Hinduism, questions on Ayurveda, geography is about the places present in texts. They should be related to Hinduism and should ask religious questions. That is the criteria for being on-topic.

Comment: Trust Meta discussions about scope. See related question https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/540/5212 . This question is just asking what is the Hindi translation of Indian. That is not a Hinduism question and suited for [linguistics.se]. They are the translators. Not us.

Comment: @YDS Yes ur undertanding is correct. Hinduism is the religion that is based upon/derived from Hindu scriptures. So, if something is part of some scriptures it is part of Hinduism. Although I am not quite sure abt whtr this particular Q is on or off topic. But I am upvoting becoz it's sharing something useful for the readers.

Comment: What is the reference you are quoting for saying Bharatiy is the word for Hindi? You add source for something else and add the answer at the bottom. As this is off-topic, better to delete this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've also adjusted the question to hopefully make it on topic